# Find folders within a directory using a list, and copy them to a different directory

Tags: python, excel, windows

I need some help with creating a python script for this problem.

Basically I have an excel sheet with a list of patient medical record numbers:

```
10000
10001
10002
10003
etc...
```

And I have a drive with this basic format:

```
-AllImages
--A
---A1
---A2
----10004
---A3
----10005
----10006
----10007
--B
---B1
----10008
----10009
-----10009_MRI
-----10009_CT
---B2...
```

And the desired output would be:

```
-OutputImages
--10000
--10001
--10002
---10002_MRI
---10002_CT
--10003
etc...
```

They are not always in exact order though. So, these terminal patient folders are what I need to copy to a different directory, but they also contain other folders that also contain the medical record number in the file name as illustrated in patient 10009. I do NOT want to pull those subfolders out separately from the main patient folder, so when I search I want to stop at the highest folder with the patient medical record in the name.

I wrote a script that FINDS the folders and outputs a csv next to each medical record number saying where the image can be found or if it couldn't be found at all. However, I cannot figure out how to get it to copy those folders to a new location. This seems like a super simple operation but I can't figure it out!

Here is the current script I am running, I tried to just modify the other script I wrote with some code I found on this site, but its not working and I don't understand it well enough to know why.

```
import os
import shutil
import xlrd
import easygui
import numpy as np
import csv

#get the excel sheet
print ('Choose patient data sheet')
master_ws = 'TestDemo/TestPatientList.xlsx'
#easygui.fileopenbox()
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(master_ws)
ws = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = ws.nrows - 1
#get correct MRN column
col = int(input ('Enter the column with patient MRNs (A=0, B=1, etc): '))
#file browser for choosing which directory to index
print ('Choose directory for indexing')
RootDir1 = r'TestDemo/TestDirectory'
#easygui.diropenbox()
#choose output folder
print ('Create output folder')
TargetFolder = r'Scripts/TestDemo/TestOutputDirectory'
#easygui.diropenbox()

#sorts directory titles into array of strings
folders = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir(RootDir1))]
folders = np.asarray(folders, dtype=str)

#gets worksheet row values and puts into an array of strings
arr = [ws.row(0)]
for i in range(1,num_rows+1):
     row = np.asarray(ws.row_values(i))
     arr = np.append(arr, [row], axis = 0)

#matching between folders and arr, ie. between directory index and master sheet

for y in range(1, len(arr)):
     for root, dirs, files in os.walk((os.path.normpath(RootDir1)), topdown=False):
          for name in dirs:
               if name.find(str(int(float(str(arr[y, col]))))):
                    print ("Found" + name)
                    SourceFolder = os.path.join(root,name)
                    shutil.copy(SourceFolder, TargetFolder) #copies to new folder
```

Comment: can you post what code have you tried?

Comment: Yes, but I just stole it from other answers on this site, I don't really understand it all, so I didn't want people to think I had some sort of base of understanding here that I didn't. But I added what I have currently

Comment: I like that you are upfront about not understanding the code you're posting. And you seem to be trying to be polite and not be a blatant leech on the community. So you've earned at least a little good will from me. Here's some sincere advice in return: To help yourself as well as the community, you have to do most of the "heavy lifting" yourself. By that I mean you have to do your own reading and experimenting to try to understand the code yourself. Then if you get to some *specific* point on which you're stuck, *that's* when you come to this site with a specific question.

Comment: What's "specific" enough? Well, hopefully you've pinpointed the part that you don't understand to just a few lines. Maybe it's funky syntax you've never encountered and can't make sense of from reading the docs (or can't even *find* in the docs). (You're reading the docs, right?!) Instead of using large chunks of code you don't understand (and then posting large chunks of code here), just play around with small chunks of code you *do* understand, and build up your program gradually from those.

Comment: Now, maybe you've been doing that. You did say: *I wrote a script that FINDS the folders and outputs a csv next to each medical record number saying where the image can be found or if it couldn't be found at all. However, I cannot figure out how to get it to copy those folders to a new location. This seems like a super simple operation but I can't figure it out!* Those few sentences sound like the basis for a reasonable Stack Overflow question! Do you understand all the code in the script that *is* working?

Comment: When you try to modify that working script to add the desired functionality, are you getting a Python traceback? If so, post it! If not, then tell us what results you *are* getting, and how that differs from what you are expecting. Good luck!